# Javascript Counter not Working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Counter Not Working In this code.Provide any Example.My code is below

```
 var rnos = jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf").val(); //Get 1 value From c#

    function getProducts() {
        alert(jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf").val());
        var decode = jQuery("#hdnfield").val();

        //  var decode = "7503960000";
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8244/api/FRecharge?rno=" + rno + "&id=" + decode,
            function (data) {
                $('#products').empty(); // Clear the table body.

                // Loop through the list of products.
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    // Add a table row for the product.
                    var row = '<td>' + val.status + '</td>';
                    $('<tr/>').html(row)  // Append the name.
                        .appendTo($('#products'));

                });
            });

        rnos = rnos + 1; 
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf").val()=$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf").val(rnos);//Increment Value and assign to Hidden field
    }
```

=-=-=-=-=-===-

I am already try:

$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf").val()=$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf").val(rnos);//
And 
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf").val(rnos)

Alert always show 1.

Comment: This Function is work on Button Click.One More  thing I have to know how call this function after saving data in database.(basically this function get value from database)

Comment: I see with my little eye, ***errors*** !

Comment: adeneo wht type of error you see ?

Comment: @adeneo you've got pretty much big eyes :D

Comment: Guys if u r taking about rns variable.If yes than it's not a issue.Main Problem is that I need to use counter.

Comment: Start with the first line, `val()` returns a string, so `"1" + 1` is `"11"`, not `2`. Then it's the ajax call, are you sure that works, remember that **ports**, protocols and host must match, unless it's CORS or JSONP. Then it's the last line of code, `$(element).val() = 'value'` is just wrong

Comment: Adeneo Can u tell me how to use this

Answer (score 0):

Thnx Guys I get Answer (increase the value in hidden field .I m set 0 value on page load time)

```
 var startElement = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnf");
 var value = parseInt(startElement.val());
 alert(value);
 //startElement.val(value + 1);
 var rnos = startElement.val(value + 1);
 //alert(rnos);`
```